# Misplacement of axis labes

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics

How could I correct a misplacement in the axis labels, when using ggplot2?

The following image shows the lag. The origin is misplaced and the ends of each axis are also.

[image]

The image was generated from this data:

```
library(viridis)
library(ggthemes)
library(ggplot2)

plot.data <- structure(list(Porcentagem = c("0", "0.1", "0.2", "0", "0.1", 
"0.2", "0", "0.1", "0.2"), NObs = c("0.2", "0.2", "0.2", "0", 
"0", "0", "0.4", "0.4", "0.4"), Freq = c(0, 0, 0, 34, 0, 0, 10, 
0, 0)), .Names = c("Porcentagem", "NObs", "Freq"), row.names = c(105L, 
106L, 107L, 112L, 113L, 114L, 119L, 120L, 121L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(
  data = plot.data, 
  aes(
    x = Porcentagem,
    y = NObs)
) + geom_tile(
  aes(
    fill = Freq)
) + scale_fill_viridis(
  option="inferno"
)
```

---

This is the same idea of plot done by me, but the labels occupy the correct position. Besides the use of a different class in the *xAxis*, the plot was done in the same way, but it didn't get deformed

[image]

Comment: In the data you provided, `Porcentagem` and `NObs` are strings, so the axes are discrete (categorical) rather than numeric. So first convert them to numeric (for example, `plot.data$NObs = as.numeric(plot.data$NObs)`). Even then, however, `geom_tile` sets the tile width so that the tiles abut each other. For this particular data set, this means that the tiles extend +/- 0.05 on either side of the actual x and y values. In other words, the center of each tile is the actual (x,y) location of the data points. You can see this if you add `+ geom_point(color="white")`.

Comment: Also note that `geom_raster` (which you might want to use anyway) has `hjust` and `vjust` parameters that once can use to change the allignment.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You guys complemented one each other. Based on the instructions you gave me, I found out this link which covers the whole thing:

http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html.  .In case anyone have the same problem in the future